# css transition with angular

Tags: angularjs, css, css-transitions

Can you please help me write a css transition with angular when I click on a link ? My code doesn't work.

I'd link this div:

```
<div id="encartUserRes" class="encartRes" ng-class="{'flash': isFlash}">....</div>
```

to "flash" when I click on this link:

```
<a class="suggestPro" ng-click="isFlash=1;">...</a>
```

css:

```
#encartUserRes {
    border: 1px solid rgba(6, 180, 200, 0.9);
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    top: 27%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}
#encartUserRes.flash{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

controllers.js:

```
$scope.isFlash = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you were able to resolve the not functioning $scope part, as for the flash animation you can do it using `@keyframes` animation

```
@keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}
.flash {
    animation: flash 1s step-start 0s;
    -webkit-animation: flash 1s step-start 0s;
}
```

here's an [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/es6e6/1589/). using jQuery and no angular just for example purposes.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work, event with isFlahsh=true in the html

Comment: just tested it and it fades out, isn't that your desired outcome?

Comment: could it be that my ionic app is more complicated and there's something blocking ?

Comment: probably the problem is elsewhere, aren't you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: I am going to look for what's wrong. BTW do you know the transition syntax to make the div disappear like here and make it reappear instantly ?

Comment: it seems like you fixed the problem I'll change my answer to help you with your second part (flash/blink animation)

Comment: thanks a lot @FabioG, but with angular it doesn't work, because one the flash class is set, I can't trigger again the animation...  http://jsfiddle.net/jvw05rsk/3/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I had to change and add this:

html:

```
<a class="suggestPro" ng-click="changeisFlash();">...</a>
```

controllers.js:

```
$scope.changeisFlash = function() {
  $scope.isFlash = true;
}
```